# recommended maximum number of UILabels to be added on the screen?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a subway map as an image on the screen.
There are a few hundred stations.

I am wondering if I should include the name of stations in the map as an image file, or add them separately using

```
self.view.addSubviews(UILabel)
```

for each station names.

This would let me have a better control of updating stations' names when they change, etc.

Would be okay(performance, battery perspective) to have a few hundreds of UILabels to be added as subviews?

Comment: You would probably be better off implementing custom drawing in this case using `CATiledLayer`.

Comment: What about adding uilabels onto the screen for station names? I actually have implemented CATiledLayer for the map already